# Looking for toDataUrl guidance

Tags: javascript, image, data-url

Cut to the chase... I'd like to take a local image file, use javascript to create a dataurl value from that image. I'm not totally sure how to go about doing that. I have looked at a bunch of code examples and i'm not real sure on what exactly they are doing with the canvas stuff. Also can I even hope to access local files for this? I am willing to bet that, that would be a security risk and javascript wouldn't be able to reach out past it's sandbox.

Essentially, with REAL paraphrased JS, this is what i'm looking to do...

```
var imgTest = "/tmp/prev/localimage.jpeg";
var imgTest = imgTest.toDataUrl;
document.write(imgTest);
```

The end result hopefully being a dataurl string printed to the webpage, "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQE..."

Does this make sense? I just want that dataurl information in a variable.

Thanks so much for your great advice StackOverflow!

Comment: Are you trying to do this without any calls to a server, i.e. for the conversion of the image to the data:image format? Also, are you asking about the accessing of local files or the conversion to base64?

Comment: Yes, this would be a local only environment. Everything is done client side. I would like to accomplish conversion of a local file to base64. I doubt I would be able to access local files with JavaScript however. I was thinking perhaps I could pull the image somehow from the DOM and have it converted to base64? I think that requires some interaction with a canvas element but i'm not quite sure how exactly that procedure works... Thanks @Dancrumb !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The `toDataURL()` method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a SECURITY_ERR exception is thrown." [Source](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/)

To me, this sounds like it will not work with local files and is used to generate encoded image data from content drawn on an HTML5 canvas.

Looking at the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement) confirms that `toDataURL()` is a function specifically for the canvas object, not an image object.

If I understand correctly, you may be able to draw the image on a canvas of the same dimensions and then use the toDataURL() method to generate your encoded data.  This, of course, assuming the image file resides in the same location as the JavaScript code.

Comment: I choose this as the answer because through banging my head against the wall over and over, I simply could not access a local resource for my needs using JS. I learned this the hard way! Your answer is most inline with what my situation was. My work around ended up being to generate the base64 data inline in the html document in hidden spans using python, avoiding JS altogether for the creation of the base64 data! Thanks you everyone for all your helpful answers! I learned about file reading as well which will be handy in future projects!

Answer (score 2):

MDN has a [pretty neat and simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#Example) that demonstrates exactly what you want:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Image preview example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
  document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};

function loadImageFile() {
  if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }
  var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImageFile();">
  <form name="uploadForm">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E%0A%3Csvg%20width%3D%22153%22%20height%3D%22153%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%0A%20%3Cg%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctitle%3ENo%20image%3C/title%3E%0A%20%20%3Crect%20id%3D%22externRect%22%20height%3D%22150%22%20width%3D%22150%22%20y%3D%221.5%22%20x%3D%221.500024%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%20stroke%3D%22%23666666%22%20fill%3D%22%23e1e1e1%22/%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22matrix%286.66667%2C%200%2C%200%2C%206.66667%2C%20-960.5%2C%20-1099.33%29%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%20font-family%3D%22Fantasy%22%20font-size%3D%2214%22%20id%3D%22questionMark%22%20y%3D%22181.249569%22%20x%3D%22155.549819%22%20stroke-width%3D%220%22%20stroke%3D%22%23666666%22%20fill%3D%22%23000000%22%3E%3F%3C/text%3E%0A%20%3C/g%3E%0A%3C/svg%3E" alt="Image preview" /></td>
          <td><input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Send" /></p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Try it out.](https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3698/image_upload_preview.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an image object, draw it to canvas, and then call the toDataURL() on the canvas. Like so:

```
function draw() {
  var dataURL;
  var that = this;
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img,0,0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    // can call some other function once the image is loaded and you have the dataURL, e.g.
    that.onDataURL(dataURL);
  };
  img.src = '/files/4531/backdrop.png';
}

function onDataURL(dataURL) {
  console.log(dataURL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can offer a input[type=file] to the user where he can select a image to use.

After that you can access the image data via FileReader.

This is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

The FileReader API also offers a readAsDataURL method which should get you the Base64 String.